# increment variable in a string in shell script

Tags: bash, sh

I have a string  which comes from a variable
I want to increment it. how can i do that using shell script?

this is my input which comes from a variable:

```
abc-ananya-01
```

output should be:

```
abc-ananya-02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this:

```
kent$  echo "abc-ananya-07"|awk -F'-' -v OFS='-' '{$3=sprintf("%02d",++$3)}7' 
abc-ananya-08
```

The above codes do the increment and keep your number format.

Answer (score 3):

It is shorter:

```
a=abc-lhg-08
echo ${a%-*}-`printf "%02d" $((10#${a##*-}+1))`
abc-lhg-09
```

Even better:

```
a=abc-lhg-08
printf "%s-%02d\n" ${a%-*} $((10#${a##*-}+1))
abc-lhg-09
```

Comment: Nothing in this answer requires `bash` 4, or even any `bash` extensions; it will work in any POSIX shell.

Comment: In my first example I found a fundamental problem and I corrected it.
The original first example can't work with abc-lhg-08 or abc-lhg-09 inputs.
I had to suppress the auto octal interpretation of bash when there was a leading zero, with
explicit indication of radix ten 10#.
I show you what I mean: `a=08;echo $(($a))
bash: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
a=08;echo $((10#$a))
8` And there is no reason to use both echo and printf so the second example more fits.

Answer (score 2):

Bash string manipulations can be used here.

```
a='abc-ananya-07'
let last=$(echo ${a##*-}+1)
echo ${a%-*}-$(printf "%02d" $last)
```

[image]

Comment: This solution doesn't work with these inputs: a='abc-ananya-08' or a='abc-ananya-09' bash error: bash: let: last=08: value too great for base (error token is "08") My correct answer is here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/36934535/4581311]

Answer (score 1):

With pure Bash it is a bit long:

```
IFS="-" read -r -a arr <<< "abc-ananya-01"
last=10#${arr[${#arr}-1]}    # to prevent getting 08, when Bash 
                             # understands it is a number in base 8
last=$(( last + 1 ))
arr[${#arr}-1]=$(printf "%02d" $last)
( IFS="-"; echo "${arr[*]}" )
```

This reads into an array, increments the last element and prints it back.

It returns:

```
abc-ananya-02
```

Comment: `bash` 4.3 now allows negative subscripts, so you can write `last=$((${arr[-1]}+1))` (it's short enough to make a one-liner reasonable).

Comment: In fact, you can use `printf -v arr[-1] "%02d" $((arr[-1]+1))` to avoid the need for the temporary `last` variable altogether.

Comment: This solution doesn't work with these inputs: a='abc-ananya-08' or a='abc-ananya-09' bash error: bash: let: last=08: value too great for base (error token is "08") My correct answer is here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/36934535/4581311]

Comment: @LászlóSzilágyi yep, hadn't checked that one. Updated, thanks.