# Get last element in Bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

Say I have an array:

```
arr=(a b c d e f)
```

If I want to get the last element of the array, I normally have to get the total number of elements, substract one and use that number to call as an index:

```
$ echo ${#arr[@]}
6
$ echo ${arr[${#arr[@]}-1]}
f
```

However, [I see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36933682/increment-variable-in-a-string-in-shell-script/36933953#comment61474656_36933953) that recently (Bash 4.2 - 4.3) you can use negative indexes:

```
$ echo ${arr[-1]}
f
$ echo ${arr[-2]}
e
```

So I am wondering: when was this introduced? Is it also usable by other shells like ksh, zsh...?

My research shows:

[Bash-4.3-rc1 available for FTP](http://bug-bash.gnu.narkive.com/WtOy6UGI/bash-4-3-rc1-available-for-ftp)

> a. Fixed a bug that caused assignment to an unset variable using a
>   negative subscript to result in a segmentation fault.
>
> b. Fixed a bug that caused assignment to a string variable using a
>   negative subscript to use the incorrect index.
>
> ...
>
> x. The shell now allows assigning, referencing, and unsetting elements
>   of indexed arrays using negative subscripts (a[-1]=2, echo ${a[-1]})
>   which count back from the last element of the array.

And [Bash manual 4.3, on Arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays)

> Referencing an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to
>   referencing with a subscript of 0. If the subscript used to reference
>   an element of an indexed array evaluates to a number less than zero,
>   it is interpreted as relative to one greater than the maximum index of
>   the array, so negative indices count back from the end of the array,
>   and an **index of -1 refers to the last element**.

But I wonder if this was already in Bash 4.2, since the first resource mentions a bug that was fixed.

Comment: Nice, checking a palindrome has become much easy now .

Comment: To answer your other question: It's in zsh too. Don't know about ksh.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I can see in https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES, the new feature is in this part :

> This document details the changes between this version, **bash-4.3-alpha,
>   and the previous version, bash-4.2-release**.
>
> ...
>
> x. The shell now allows assigning, referencing, and unsetting elements of indexed arrays using negative subscripts (a[-1]=2, echo ${a[-1]}) which count back from the last element of the array.

The fix in :

> This document details the changes between this version, **bash-4.3-beta2, and theprevious version, bash-4.3-beta**.
>
> 1  Changes to Bash
>
> a. Fixed a bug that caused
>   assignment to an unset variable using a negative subscript to result in a segmentation fault.
>
> b. Fixed a bug that caused assignment to a string variable using a negative subscript to use the incorrect index.

It a fix of a new feature in Bash 4.3.