# How to access last item in bash array on Mac OS?

Tags: arrays, bash, macos

I had to create a bash array on Mac OS as follows. The `$1` represents # of git commits you want to store in the array.

```
IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a array<<< "$(git log -n $1 | grep commit |  awk '{print $2}')"
```

I can't access last array item as `${array[-1]}`. I get the error "array: bad array subscript".

However, when I create the array on linux OS, I can access the last array item in the same way successfully.

```
readarray -t array <<< "$(git log -n $1 | grep commit |  awk '{print $2}')"
```

`echo ${array[-1]}` is successful on Linux machine but not on Mac OS machine.

Comment: Apple ships bash 3.2; this is ancient -- current releases are in the 5.x series. You have the option to install a newer one with Nix, MacPorts, Homebrew, etc.

Comment: Closely related (but assumes the answer to this question as a premise): [get last element in bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36977855/get-last-element-in-bash-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a bash too old to support negative subscripts, you end up needing to do something like:

```
echo "${array[$((${#array[@]} - 1))]}"
```